# Spring Boot + Groovy + JPA, failed to inject JpaRepository

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-data-jpa

Here is my app.groovy code:

```
package org.test

import javax.persistence.*
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository

@Grab('spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
@Grab('mysql-connector-java')

@Entity
@Table (name="owner")
class Owner {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long ownerId;
    @Column(name = 'Name')
    String name;
    @Column(name = 'DateOfBirth')
    Date dateOfBirth;
    @Column(name = 'Address')
    String address;

    @Override
    String toString() {
        return String.format(
                "Owner[id=%d, Name='%s', DateOfBirth='%s']",
                id, name, dateOfBirth);
    }
}

interface OwnerRepository extends JpaRepository<Owner, Long> {
    List<Owner> findByName(String name);
}

class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {
    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;
    @Autowired
    private OwnerRepository repository

    void run(String... args) {
        for (owner in repository.findAll()) {
            println owner
        }
    }
}
```

application.properties code:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ng4
spring.datasource.username=user_name
spring.datasource.password=********

spring.jpa.show-sql=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.database=MYSQL
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate
```

After running $ spring run app.groovy, I got following error messages:

```
Field repository in org.test.Runner required a bean of type 'org.test.OwnerRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.test.OwnerRepository' in your configuration.

...

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'runner': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'repository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.test.OwnerRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

I have tried to test inject JdbcTemplate using the same code statement, and it works fine, so I have no idea what's wrong in those code.

Please give me some suggestions, thanks very much !!

Comment: The Spring Boot version is v2.0.0.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

Actually the problem is that you also don't have `@SpringBootApplication` on top of your `Runner` class.

you're missing `@Repository` annotation on top of your `OwnerRepository`. That might be it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but when I add @Repository annotation, I got following new error messages, the Spring Boot version is v2.0.0.RELEASE:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'ownerRepository': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate [org.test.OwnerRepository]: 
Specified class is an interface

Comment: Also needs @EnableJpaRepositories annotation on Runner class.

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` should be added on top of your Runner class not Own repository.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I add ⓐRepository annotations on OwnerRepository and add ⓐSpringBootApplication, ⓐEnableJpaRepositories annotation on Runner. Then got new errors : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ownerRepository': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.test.OwnerRepository]: Specified class is an interface